# Haskell function to get part of date as string

Tags: datetime, haskell, io, monads

I have a beginner question about dates and `String` in Haskell.

I need to get part of date (year, month or day) as `String` in Haskell. I found out, that if I write the following two lines in GHCi

```
Prelude> now <- getCurrentTime
Prelude> let mon = formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%B" now
```

then `mon` is of type `String`. However, I am unable to put this in a function. I tried for instance the following:

```
getCurrMonth = do
    now <- getCurrentTime
    putStrLn (formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%B" now)
```

But this returns type `IO ()` and I need `String` (also not `IO String`, only `String`).

I understand that `do` statement creates a monad, which I don't want, but I have been unable to find any other solution for getting date in Haskell.

So, is there any way to write a function like this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to return a String representing the current time, it will *have* to be in the IO monad, as the value of the current time is always changing!

What you can do is to return a String in the IO monad:

```
> getCurrMonth :: IO String
> getCurrMonth = do
>    now <- getCurrentTime
>    return (formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%B" now)
```

then, from your top level (e.g. in main), you can pass the String around:

```
> main = do
>     s <- getCurrMonth
>     ... do something with s ...
```

Answer (score 5):

If you really want a pure function of that sort, then you need to pass in the time explicitly as a parameter.

```
import System.Locale (defaultTimeLocale)
import System.Time (formatCalendarTime, toUTCTime, getClockTime, ClockTime)

main = do now <- getClockTime
          putStrLn $ getMonthString now

getMonthString :: ClockTime -> String
getMonthString = formatCalendarTime defaultTimeLocale "%B" . toUTCTime
```

Notice how `getMonthString` can be pure since the IO action `getClockTime` is performed elsewhere.

I used the [old-time](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/old-time/latest/doc/html/System-Time.html) functions, because I was [testing it out on codepad](http://codepad.org/wJaS9LKO), which apparently doesn't have the newer time package. :( I'm new to the old time functions so this might be off a couple hours since it uses `toUTCTime`.

Comment: +1 for showing how to keep the "impure part" as small as possible.

Answer (score 2):

As Don said, there's no way to avoid using monads in this situation. Remember that Haskell is a pure functional language, and therefore a function must always return the same output given a particular input. Haskell.org provides a great explanation and introduction [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/IO_inside) that is certainly worth looking at. You'd also probably benefit from monad introduction like [this one](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html) or a Haskell I/O tutorial like [this one](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output). Of course there are tons more resources online you can find. Monads can initially be daunting, but they're really not as difficult as they seem at first.

Oh, and I strongly advise against using `unsafePerformIO`. There's a very good reason it has the word "unsafe" in the name, and it was definitely not created for situations like this. Using it will only lead to bad habits and problems down the line.

Good luck learning Haskell!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your links, I can finally understand monads a little better. The way we are taught Haskell at school is utterly confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get just a String, it has to be IO String.  This is because getCurrMonth is not a pure function, it returns different values at different times, so it has to be in IO.